# Include multiple patterns in regex word break

Tags: regex, go

I have the following program which uses regex to search for a pattern and replaces it a key word.

Sample as shown below will replace names like "Incorp","Inc.","Inc corp" with "Inc".

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func replaceWholeWord(input string, patterns map[string]string) string {
    for searchPattern, replacePattern := range patterns {
        re, _ := regexp.Compile(`(?i)(^|\s)` + regexp.QuoteMeta(searchPattern) + `(\s|$)`)
        input = re.ReplaceAllString(input, "${1}"+replacePattern+"${2}")
    }
    return input
}

func main() {

    patterns := map[string]string{"Inc.": "Inc", "Incorp.": "Inc", "Incorporation": "Inc", ", Incorpa.": "Inc"}
    fmt.Println(replaceWholeWord("ABC Inc.", patterns))
    fmt.Println(replaceWholeWord("ABC Incorp.", patterns))
    fmt.Println(replaceWholeWord("ABC InCorp.", patterns))
    fmt.Println(replaceWholeWord("ABC InCorporation", patterns))
    fmt.Println(replaceWholeWord("ABC , InCorpa.", patterns))
}
```

As you can see this performance intensive as the number of patterns increase. I want to build regular expression only once and do the search and replace operation. I am facing tough time to add the those multiple
patterns in a single regex without breaking the functionality.

Edit:
I modified my program to avoid building the regexes  only if the word has the pattern, this way I have avoided to the performance hit. 
Please feel free to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a GO developer, but a single Regular Expression pattern for what you have shown would be:

---

```
(In(c|C)(\.|orp(\.|a\.|oration)))$
```

UPDATE:  Found the GO way.

---

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {

    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)^(.*)(?:Inc(?:\.|orp(?:\.|a|oration)??\.))(.*)$`)

    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("ABC Inc.", "${1}Inc${2}"))
    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("ABC Incorp.", "${1}Inc${2}"))
    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("ABC InCorporation.", "${1}Inc${2}"))
    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("ABC InCorpa.", "${1}Inc${2}"))

}
```

---

```
ABC Inc
ABC Inc
ABC Inc
ABC Inc
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an "or":

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {

    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?i)^(.*)(?:Inc\.|Incorp\.|Incorporation\.|Incorpa\.)(.*)$`)

    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("ABC Inc.", "${1}Inc${2}"))
    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("ABC Incorp.", "${1}Inc${2}"))
    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("ABC InCorporation.", "${1}Inc${2}"))
    fmt.Println(re.ReplaceAllString("ABC InCorpa.", "${1}Inc${2}"))

}
```

[See Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0H6fQVbwP-F):

```
ABC Inc
ABC Inc
ABC Inc
ABC Inc
```

Comment: I want to use or. The example I provided covers only one case, I would like to add many search and replace patterns, and I was thinking to form the regexes dynamically and now I am realizing that it may not be in the scope of regex.

Answer (score 0):

If all you 'search & replace' are done on whole words, you can simply turn your `string` into a slice of words and construct a new `string` which replaces each word present in your `map` with its counterpart:

```
var buffer bytes.Buffer
for _, word := range words {
    if val, ok := patterns[word]; ok {
        word = val
    }
    buffer.WriteString(word)
    buffer.WriteString(" ")
}
```

Comment: I very much would have preferred this approach. But the pattern can be made up of multiple words which has spaces. E.g. "Corp Inc"